# Multiple child processes not running till the end in Node.js

Tags: node.js, spawn

I'm working on a Node.js application where I need to spawn multiple child processes using spawn to perform some asynchronous operations. Each child process is responsible for processing an Excel file (which is the output of another `spawn` process) and emitting progress updates. However, I'm encountering an issue where only the last child process seems to run till the end, while the others do not complete their execution.

Here's an overview of the relevant part of my code:

```
var transcriptionProcess = spawn('conda',['run', '-n', 'whisper','--no-capture-output', 'python','-u', './pipeline/transcription.py'].concat(diarisationResults.flat()));
// Event handler for the stdout of the transcription process
transcriptionProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  try {
    // Parsing the JSON data
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    // Handling the parsed JSON data
    // ...

    // Spawning the child process for umap
    var umapProcess = spawn('conda', ['run', '-n', 'whisper', '--no-capture-output', 'python', '-u', './pipeline/umaps.py', json.excel]);
    // ...

    // Handling stdout for the umap child process
    umapProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      try {
        // Parsing the JSON data
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        // Handling the parsed JSON data
        // ...
      } catch (error) {
        // Handling the parsing error
        // ...
      }
    });

    // Handling stderr for the umap child process
    umapProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`Error: ${data.toString()}`);
    });

    // Handling the exit event for the umap child process
    umapProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        // Process exited successfully
        // ...
      } else {
        console.error(`Process exited with code ${code}.`);
      }
    });

    // ...
  } catch (error) {
    // Handling the parsing error
    // ...
  }
});

// ...
```

I have also tried storing the child processes in an array (umapProcesses) and attempting to access the last element (umapProcesses[umapProcesses.length - 1]), but that doesn't seem to help neither.
I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to resolve this issue and ensure that all child processes run till the end.